# Was Net View fixed on windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-error-reporting

Recently Net View stopped working with error message 1231 when there were capitalization changes or numerals in a server name. Was this fixed?

Comment: @Alex hmm, are you sure about that? I just tried `net view` on a server here and it was not case sensitive.

Comment: @wysiwyg I removed my comment since it looks misleading, what I wanted to say is that Microsoft guidance recommends to use for computer names uppercase characters. It comes from era before w2k. OP asked in another question about enumeration of network shares and I thought it is related to this question.